# Display messd up with weird characters in Gentoo after `cat` a binary file

Tags: terminal, gentoo

I ran `cat /etc/localtime` to see the contents of `/etc/localtime` - however it's a binary file, so my console became like this:

[image]

You may notice the red text in screenshot is "LiveCD"; commands can be executed correctly, but they display in a weird way. I'm in the middle of an installation process, so I'd prefer to avoid rebooting. How can I return my display to normal?

**UPDATE**: after running `make menuconfig` to enter a GUI and quitting, it's back to normal.

Comment: The reason "make menuconfig" fixes your screen is that the program run is linked to a terminal handling library (libncurses I think?) and as part of the initialization of the program, it will reset the terminal to a known state.

Comment: just a note: this problem is not tied with the Gentoo distribution, it happens on every Linux distro. this scenario is typical for non-UTF8 console outputs.

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/68796/how-to-correct-the-unrecongnizable-code-in-my-debian

Answer (score 25, accepted):

yeah, you've output (probably) binary to the console, and its faffed up the mapping.

In situations like this, the command you want is `reset`.

hit return (so you know you have a blank line), type in `reset` and hit return again. :-D

Answer (score 8):

An alternative to the reset command is to output the ASCII SI (shift in) character, decimal value 15. This can be entered with Ctrl-O, and should work on any (even ancient) unix in case it laks the reset command.

```
prompt>
prompt>echo ^V^O
```

Comment: This worked for me whereas `reset` did not

Comment: Oh, I had completely forgotten about ^V.  Thanks for reminding me! =)

Answer (score 1):

Try running the `reset` command.  If hitting return before and after the reset command doesn't work, try control-J.

Also, Alt-F2 to switch to an alternate terminal can bypass the issue temporarily.