# Reset garbled Terminal window on OS X

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal

I was connected to a linux server over SSH.  After performing the following command

```
cat dmesg.1.gz
```

the prompt on my SSH session changed from `conor@linux:~$` to `␌⎺┼⎺⎼@┌␋┼┤│:·/┌⎺±⎽$`

Any text I typed into the terminal was also garbled, even after disconnecting from the SSH session by typing `exit`, the terminal session which was now with my mac, was still garbled.  I resolved the issue by closing the terminal window and opening a new one.

Is there any way to reset the terminal without closing the window and reopening such as a key combination?

Comment: Also, see [How to correct the unrecongnizable code in my debian?](http://superuser.com/q/68796).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your terminal has been shifted into “alternate character set” mode. To shift it back out, type

```
tput rmacs
```

at your (garbled) shell prompt. Your typing will appear garbled, too, but it will be back to normal after this command finishes.

Comment: Picked this as the best answer because it explained the reason why it happened in addition to resolving the issue.  Mr. Mans answer worked too.

Comment: worked on a Linux terminal too :)

Answer (score 7):

I have had this same problem. To fix, click on Shell --> Send Reset. And if that doesn't work. Shell --> Hard Reset. This will reset it without you having to close and reopen the terminal.

Comment: +1 this is the only solution that worked for me, when something went wrong on the remote side of an ssh connection.

Comment: ⌘R — Send Reset

Comment: The hard reset worked for me, but I had to wait a couple of minutes before I got the command line back.  So patience may be necessary...

Answer (score 7):

Typing "reset" at the command line (even if you cannot see what you are tying) often helps.

Answer (score 0):

After trying the previous answers without any effect I took a look at the man page:
tput reset