# How to redraw Linux console

Tags: linux, console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to correct the unrecognizable code in my debian?](https://superuser.com/questions/68796/how-to-correct-the-unrecognizable-code-in-my-debian)

I printed the contents of a file(/var/log/wtmp) with non-ascii characters in my Bash console, which caused my console to now display garbled characters.

How to I reset my console?

Answer (score 7):

Try **`reset`**.

(You can read the wtmp database with `who`, `last` or `utmpdump`.)