# Tmux visual artifacts, strange character map

Tags: tmux

[image]

It’s running a java program outputting console log.

### Config file

```
# visuals
set -g status-bg black
set -g status-fg white
set -g status-left '#S (#[fg=green]#(whoami)@#(hostname)#[fg=white])'
set -g status-left-length 32
set -g status-right-length 60
set -g status-right '(#[fg=red]#(cat /etc/issue | head -1)#[fg=white])'

setw -g window-status-format "[ #W ]"
setw -g window-status-current-format "[ #W ]"
setw -g window-status-fg white
setw -g window-status-current-fg cyan
setw -g window-status-current-attr default

# Set the prefix to ^A.
unbind C-b
set -g prefix ^A
bind a send-prefix

# Bind appropriate commands similar to screen.
# lockscreen ^X x
unbind ^X
bind ^X lock-server
unbind x
bind x lock-server

# screen ^C c
unbind ^C
bind ^C new-window
bind c new-window

# detach ^D d
unbind ^D
bind ^D detach

# displays *
unbind *
bind * list-clients

# next ^@ ^N sp n
unbind ^@
bind ^@ next-window
unbind ^N
bind ^N next-window
unbind " "
bind " " next-window
unbind n
bind n next-window

# title A
unbind A
bind A command-prompt "rename-window %%"

# other ^A
unbind ^A
bind ^A last-window

# prev ^H ^P p ^?
unbind ^H
bind ^H previous-window
unbind ^P
bind ^P previous-window
unbind p
bind p previous-window
unbind BSpace
bind BSpace previous-window

# windows ^W w
unbind ^W
bind ^W list-windows
unbind w
bind w list-windows

# quit \
unbind \
bind \ confirm-before "kill-server"

# kill K k
unbind K
bind K confirm-before "kill-window"
unbind k
bind k confirm-before "kill-window"

# redisplay ^L l
unbind ^L
bind ^L refresh-client
unbind l
bind l refresh-client

# split -v |
unbind |
bind | split-window

# " windowlist -b
unbind '"'
bind '"' choose-window
```

Command input works, I can kinda see that familiar output too (not every character has that problem) but it’s like character map was completely replaced by rubbish.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work correctly without tmux?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to correct the unrecognizable code in my debian?](http://superuser.com/questions/68796/how-to-correct-the-unrecognizable-code-in-my-debian)